# "sola" vs "unuope"

Tags: word-usage

I came across both of these words when studying on Duolingo.

"Sola" was translated as "alone", and "unuope" was translated as "by myself", or literally "in a group of one", which seems to mean the same thing.

Are the two words totally interchangeable, or are there some subtle differences in meaning?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"sola" means "solitary, alone", whereas "unuope" means "one at a time".

> La sola hundo trinkas akvon. / The solitary dog drinks water.

or

> La hundo trinkas akvon sole / The dog drinks water alone (ie on its own).

v.s.

> La hundoj trinkas akvon unuope / The dogs drink water one at a time.

Comment: ah right so there is a subtle difference :) thanks!